# How to repeat one wpf user control multiple times in wpf windows form according to database entry

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am working on WPF application, I want create one user control that contain one grid with 5 columns and i want to repeat this control on WPF window form according to data fetched from database. It might be repeat one time or more than one.

Answer (score 0):

the ItemsControl (or List) may help you here. You can bind the ItemsSource Property to your ViewModel IEnumerable Property where your DBEntries are stored.

With the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate Property you can define what DataTemplate is used for each Item of the Enumeration.

KR,
incureforce

Comment: Thanks,
I have created a grid user control and now I need to use it in WPF window. Could you please give me sample code that How I will use ItemsControl (or List) to display grid user control multiple times.